# Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header in Jekyll site in Github

Tags: google-chrome, jekyll

After upgrading to latest Google Chrome I'm getting the following error.

> Font from origin 'http://fonts.gstatic.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Because of this the web fonts are not working. I know that if I add Access-Control-Allow-Origin HTTP header it will work. But my site is a Jekyll site and it is hosted in using Github.

So how to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` http header in Jekyll generated site hosted in Github?

Comment: I don't understand why some one down vote with out a comment.

Comment: neither do I. But it happens.

Comment: I was using ```Open Sans``` so I downloaded the font from https://github.com/FontFaceKit/open-sans so I don't need to worry about the proxy settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Font in gstatic.com are served with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` header.
As stated [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/troubleshooting), it can be a proxy problem.

One thing is sure, you can't set this header yourself on Github pages.

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to an old question, but hopefully it will help someone.

If you are accessing Google Maps API or Fonts using http, try using the https version instead.